# Predeployment of PersistenceUnit failed with EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Am new to JPA and starting out with EclipseLink. Taking help from tutorial I started creating my first JPA project consiting of an Entity (automatically created using JPA tools), a simple main class firing the most basic select query. However when i try running the main class I get a Predeployment of PersistenceUnit failed exception. Am using SQL server express 2008 and querying sample AdventureWorks database. Am able to connect to database (using Database Development Perspective). Detailed error log and Code snippets below:

**Main class**

```
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import model.Employee;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManager em =    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA2").createEntityManager();
    List<Employee> list = em.createQuery("Select * from humanresources.Employee", Employee.class).getResultList();
    for(Employee e : list)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getBirthDate());
    }
}
 }
```

**Entity**

```
         package model;

         import java.io.Serializable;
         import javax.persistence.*;
         import java.sql.Timestamp;

        @Entity
        public class Employee implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
        @Column(name="BusinessEntityID")
    private int businessEntityID;

    @Column(name="BirthDate")
    private Object birthDate;

    @Column(name="Gender")
    private Object gender; 

    @Column(name="HireDate")
    private Object hireDate;

    @Column(name="JobTitle")
    private Object jobTitle;

  @Column(name="MaritalStatus");
    private Object maritalStatus;

@Column(name="ModifiedDate")
private Timestamp modifiedDate;

@Column(name="NationalIDNumber")
private Object nationalIDNumber;

@Column(name="OrganizationLevel")
private short organizationLevel;

@Column(name="OrganizationNode")
private String organizationNode;

private String rowguid;

@Column(name="SickLeaveHours")
private short sickLeaveHours;

@Column(name="VacationHours")
private short vacationHours;

public Employee() {
}

public int getBusinessEntityID() {
    return this.businessEntityID;
}

public void setBusinessEntityID(int businessEntityID) {
    this.businessEntityID = businessEntityID;
}

public Object getBirthDate() {
    return this.birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(Object birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public Object getGender() {
    return this.gender;
}

public void setGender(Object gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Object getHireDate() {
    return this.hireDate;
}

public void setHireDate(Object hireDate) {
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
}

public Object getJobTitle() {
    return this.jobTitle;
}

public void setJobTitle(Object jobTitle) {
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}


public Object getMaritalStatus() {
    return this.maritalStatus;
}

public void setMaritalStatus(Object maritalStatus) {
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
}

public Timestamp getModifiedDate() {
    return this.modifiedDate;
}

public void setModifiedDate(Timestamp modifiedDate) {
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
}

public Object getNationalIDNumber() {
    return this.nationalIDNumber;
}

public void setNationalIDNumber(Object nationalIDNumber) {
    this.nationalIDNumber = nationalIDNumber;
}

public short getOrganizationLevel() {
    return this.organizationLevel;
}

public void setOrganizationLevel(short organizationLevel) {
    this.organizationLevel = organizationLevel;
}

public String getOrganizationNode() {
    return this.organizationNode;
}

public void setOrganizationNode(String organizationNode) {
    this.organizationNode = organizationNode;
}

public String getRowguid() {
    return this.rowguid;
}

public void setRowguid(String rowguid) {
    this.rowguid = rowguid;
}

public short getSickLeaveHours() {
    return this.sickLeaveHours;
}

public void setSickLeaveHours(short sickLeaveHours) {
    this.sickLeaveHours = sickLeaveHours;
}

public short getVacationHours() {
    return this.vacationHours;
}

public void setVacationHours(short vacationHours) {
    this.vacationHours = vacationHours;
}

 }
```

**Persistence.XML (under Meta-INF folder)**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JPA2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Employee</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="SQLServer"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2008"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="Username"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Username"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
           Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-                  5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
           Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence        archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1ac04e8
           Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception   [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486):          org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
           Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JPA2] failed.
           Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
           Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute  [hireDate] on the entity class [class model.Employee] is not a valid type for a serialized  mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
            at   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPer sistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvi der.java:118)
            at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
           Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018]  (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
           Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JPA2] failed.
           Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
           Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute   [hireDate] on the entity class [class model.Employee] is not a valid type for a serialized  mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenc eException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1556)
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImp l.java:1547)
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer .java:98)
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvi der.java:108)
    ... 3 more
           Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
           Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JPA2] failed.
           Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services -             2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
           Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute  [hireDate] on the entity class [class model.Employee] is not a valid type for a serialized   mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManage rSetupException.java:221)
                ... 7 more
           Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7155] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
           Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute  [hireDate] on the entity class [class model.Employee] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
            at  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForSerializedAttribute(ValidationException.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.converters.SerializedMetadata.process(SerializedMetadata.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processSerialized(MappingAccessor.java:1807)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processJPA Converters(MappingAccessor.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMap pingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processMappingAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processMappingAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:1526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1718)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1484)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of the learning process is being used to reading stack traces. The line you need is:

```
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute  [hireDate] on the entity class [class model.Employee] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.
```

What does your `Employee` class look like?

EDIT

as Chris has noted your attributes are not Serializable. Make your dates into java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar or java.sql.Date. The first 2 require an @Temporal annotation with a TemporalType. Each of these would allow your example to run, but you should be aware of the differences in what will get stored.

You should also change your other attributes to Serializable types such as String for jobTitle.

hope this helps

Comment: As I mentioned the Entity class was auto-generated using JPA and hence implements Serializable by default. Moreover I have tried stripping the Entity class to a single int property, but still no luck. I have added details for Entity class also in the question above

Comment: All your attribute types within employee are of type Object which is not serializable, and not likely what you want.  Hiredate mentioned in the error for example seems like it should be a java.sql.Date instead

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever get this sorted?

I noticed that in your entity class, your Employee entity is in a package called model (the default package created by the IDE) whereas in your persistence.xml and main method - you have it in a humanresource package.